# SSIS Data conversion transformation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, decimal, etl, data-conversion

in SSIS I read a csv file with column format - for example `1.25` or `2.50`.
In the datatransformation task I transform into decimal `dt_decimal` scala 2.
In the datatable the column has the format decimal(18,2).

The data will be stored with `125.00` or `25.00` instead of `1.25` and `2.50`.

What do I have to adjust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible Issue causes

**(1) Data type mismatch**

I think that a similar issue is caused by data type mismatch between source and destination, or data transformation output and Destination.

**(2) Numeric separators**

Another cause may be if the numeric values contains a comma `,` as formatting such as thousands commas `1,000,000` and decimal separator `.` like `1.02`.

---

## Possible solutions

**(1) Specify data type in source**

To prevent this issue to be caused by data transformations and if your source data is formatted well. Then there is no need for Data Transformation. Inside the `Flat File Connection Manager` editor. GoTo Advanced Tab, Select the column that contains decimal and change its data type (try `DT_NUMERIC` and `DT_DECIMAL`) and precision and scale property.

[image]

If the issue still happening, be sure that both input and output has same metadata (precision and scale).

**(2) Derived Column**

Or you should use a Derived Column Transformation with a similar expression:

```
(DT_NUMERIC,18,2)[COLUMN]
```

**(3) Replace Separator using derived column**

You can replace separator using a derived column

```
(DT_NUMERIC,18,2)REPLACE([COLUMN], ",", ".")
```